# Return data from a screen and add it to a stream

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter, rxdart

I am trying to get data back from a screen after it closes, then add it to a stream controller in my BLoC. However when I try to retrieve the value using _bloc.streamController.value it is null. The stream controller is a BehaviorSubject.

```
  void _getDataFromSomeScreen(context) async {
    final data = await Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SomeScreen()))
        .then((onValue) {});

    _bloc.streamController.sink.add(data);
  }
```

Other options that I have tried includes calling sink.add inside the then statement, passing my bloc into the function.

If I remove the 'async' and 'await' and just hard code a value it seems to work. Why is the async causing my data to not save to my stream controller?

```
  void _getDataFromSomeScreen(context) {
   _bloc.streamController.sink.add('some data');
  }
```

How can I return data from a screen and add it to my stream controller?

Comment: Try removing the `.then()` - just await the result of `Navigator.push()`

Comment: @RichardHeap I've tried that. I've also tried setting the stream inside the then statement. I've also tried passing my bloc into the function.

Comment: are you sure the result from final data = await ... is not null ?

Comment: @diegoveloper Yes I double checked to make sure its not null. I even had a if (data != null) check but removed it before posting the question.

Comment: if you add _bloc.streamController.sink.add("testtt"); on your first code, does it works ?

Comment: Yes it will add "testtt" to the stream but then when I check _bloc.streamController.value in another part of the code the value is null. Is it possible calling Navigator.push is resetting my bloc? I have a Provider which contains the bloc. The bloc is retrieved by calling Provider.of(context) inside the build method.

Answer (score 0):

You should not to combine 2 ways of working with Futures.

1. You can use async/await method.

   ```
   Future<void> _getDataFromSomeScreen(context) async {
     final data = await Navigator.push(
           context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SomeScreen()));
     _bloc.streamController.sink.add(data);
   }
   ```
2. You can use "old fashion" method.

   ```
   void _getDataFromSomeScreen(context) {
     Navigator.push(
       context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SomeScreen()))
     .then((data) => _bloc.streamController.sink.add(data));
   }
   ```

Comment: First method is preferable because it looks like synchronous programming style.